insert into MS Access table using .to_sql()
I am currently using ms sql server to insert and/or select data using podbc library. I need to be able to do the samething using MS Access db.  Any ideas how I could insert into ms access table using pydobc.
I am currently doing this in ms sql server:
import pyodbc

try 
    engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://sqlserver_unc,15001/db_name?driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server?trusted_connection=yes", fast_executemany=True)

    df.to_sql('<table_name>', con=engine, if_exists='append', method='multi', index=False, dtype=None)

except Exeption as e:
   print(str(e))


This question is similar to: How to connect MS Access to Python using pyodbc. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If your python code is running on Windows then you can use the sqlalchemy-access dialect for SQLAlchemy. (I am the maintainer of that dialect.) For example:
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("access+pyodbc://@your_dsn")

df = pd.DataFrame(…)
df.to_sql('<table_name>', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)

